# c++ program crash when executing the function that allocates memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

To be honest, this is an homework assignment, which is about pointers and dynamic memory allocation. This program simulates the manipulation of file directories. Since it contains several files, so I would just paste a few parts here.The program crashed when I executed the function for the third time. I have looked up some solutions for debugging this kind of program crash, but still can't fix it.

```
struct fs_node
{
    char* name;
    fs_node* parent_directory;
    fs_node** content;
    int no_of_content;

};


bool loop_for_md (fs_node* current_directory, const char* dir_name)
{
    //current_directory is initialized in the main.cpp
    //find out whether the content contains the same name as dir_name

    if(current_directory->content==NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<= current_directory->no_of_content; i++)

        {
            if(strcmp(current_directory->content[i]->name, dir_name)==0)
                return false;
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


bool make_dir (fs_node* current_directory, const char* dir_name) 
{
    if(current_directory->content==NULL)
    {
        fs_node** n = new fs_node*[20];
        current_directory->content = n;
        fs_node *x = new fs_node();
        current_directory->content[current_directory->no_of_content]=x;
        x->parent_directory = current_directory;
        x->name = new char[100];
        strcpy(x->name, dir_name);
        current_directory->no_of_content++;

        delete x;
        x=0;


    }
    else if(loop_for_md(current_directory, dir_name))//I expect that this part crashes
    {
        fs_node* x = new fs_node();

        current_directory->content[current_directory->no_of_content]=x;
        x->parent_directory = current_directory;

        x->name = new char[100];
        strcpy(x->name, dir_name);
        current_directory->no_of_content++;
        delete x;
        x=0;
    }
    else return false;


    return true;
}
```

Comment: `i<= current_directory->no_of_content` you're probably accessing one past the end.

Comment: For my taste there are a couple of `deletes` and `*` to much in this code

Comment: _"I expect that this part crashes"_ you should **know** where it crashes, preferably before asking a question here, otherwise your attempts to fix it will be just guesswork not based on facts. Either add print statements to tell you where the program got to before crashing, or run it in a debugger which will tell you exactly where it crashes.

Answer (score 4):

When you have created a new `fs_node` and inserted it into the directory tree, you shouldn't delete it - that ends the object's lifetime and you're not allowed to use it after that.

Formally, doing so has "undefined behaviour", which means that anything can happen, including a crash much later in a different piece of code or - much worse - appearing to work as intended.

Comment: But even I didn't delete the fs_node, the program still crashed.